# joining custom tables using magento commands

Tags: magento, join

I have been trying to join two custom table using magento's commands. After searching i came across [this block of generic code](http://shortbutsweetmagento.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/join-custom-table-to-product-collection.html)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name')), 
'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key',
 array('table_alias.*'), 
'schema_name_if_different');
```

Following this as template I have tried to join my tables together but have only returned errors such as `incorrect table name` or `table doesn't exist` or some other error.

Just to clear things up can someone please correct me on my understanding

`$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();`

Gets an instance of your model. Within that model is the table that holds the required data (for this example I shall call the table p)

`$collection->getSelect()`

Select data from table p

`->join()`

Requires three parameters to join two table together

PARAM1

`array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name'))`

'the alised name you give the table' => 'the table you want to add to the collection (this has been set up in the model folder)'

PARAM2

`'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key'`

This bit i don't get (it seems straight forward though)

my main table (p) doesn't have a foreign id (it has it's primary key - is that also its foreign id)?

has to be equal to the alised name you gave in param1

PARAM3

`'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key'`

get all from alised name

Where have I gone wrong on my understanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please have a look in below sql join statement, I am using it in my project and it is working perfectly.

**Syntax**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'table_name_for_join', 'main_table.your_table_field ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'table_name_for_join.join_table_field', array('field_name_you_want_to_fetch_from_db'));
```

**Working Query Example**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar', 'main_table.products_id ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id', array('value'));
```

Hope this will work for you !!