# Join model between customer entity and custom module

Tags: magento

In the Grid.php, I need to join customer/customer model with my custom model.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addNameToSelect();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('e' => 'event'), 'e.customer_id=main_table.entity_id', array('status')
    );

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Basically I need to add some more information (in this example is status) to the collection. The `event` table contains the customer_id as reference to customer_entity.entity_id. How can I do this?

Comment: Please have look in below link i have already answered for joining custom tables in magento [Joining custom tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381320/joining-custom-tables-using-magento-commands/19401573#19401573) Hope this will help you! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If there is any error you are getting you can share. Meanwhile try below updated code.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addNameToSelect();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
array('e' => 'event'), 'e.customer_id=main_table.entity_id', array('e.status') // added 'e.status' in stead of 'status'
);

$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Hope will help!