# Getting data from 2 tables in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9.1

I created 2 textension in magento along with 2 different tables. First extension store data in table-1 while second second extension store data in table-2. Now i want to display data in first extension by LeftJoin. It show data without leftjoin from first table but not showing data with leftjoin from both the tables. 
This code in block.php

```
public function methodblock()
 {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();

    $returnCollection = $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft('magento_answer', 'id_pfay_test=question_id', 
    array('*'), null , 'left');


     return $returnCollection;
 }
```

On Layout side. dislplaydata.phtml

```
<?php 
$collection =  $this->testmethodblock(); 
foreach($collection as $rows {
    echo $rows ->getData('name');
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19401573/1076075

Comment: I is not displaying any error. when i echo $returnCollection. It gives this query.    SELECT `main_table`.*, `magento_answer`.* FROM `magento_pfay_test` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `magento_answer` ON id_pfay_test=question_id . This query is running properly on mysql db.

Comment: try to print query and check where is the problem.  before return function write echo $collection->getSelect();exit;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got the answer. I use the custom query which works for me.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $qTable   = $resource->getTableName('pfay_test');
        $aTable   = $resource->getTableName('answer/answer');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM  '.$qTable.'  q  left join '.$aTable.' a ON  a.question_id=q.id_pfay_test';
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query); 
         return $results;
```